# Pulling data from an SQL database server using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter to pull data from an SQL server database. My connection is fine, but the problem is that I can only query the database once!

For example, I have two links on my web interface. One pulls data showing students details and the other is supposed to pull courses available at a college. When I click the link to pull students details, the other link won't work; it just displays nothing! Both links have been coded with valid codes and they are working only that one at a time.

How can I do this?

Comment: You should provide more details, show the code.

Comment: what if you click the second link first? How do you build the links? Do you use relative path or base_url()? do say more

Comment: Copy edited (e.g. ref. <http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/won%27t>, )

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanx i finaly got it right! I just forgot to put 'echo' behind the generate 
statement hence when i clicked that link it could'nt               
draw any table on the interface.

**WRONG ONE.**
    <?php
     $this->table->generate($getAddresses_contents);
     ?>   

**CORRECT ONE.**
 <?php
  echo $this->table->generate($getAddresses_contents);
  ?>
```